# Scale up Azure Analysis service with Windows powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-analysis-services

I'm working on a tabular model deployed on Azure Analysis Service.
We use Microsoft SSIS to load the DW and process the tabular model.

We now want to increase the QPU via SSIS or with a PowerShell script.
I found a script on SSIS http://microsoft-bitools.bl...
running a Powershell script via Runbook directly on Azure.

1- What's the difference between a Powershell script and a Powershell runbook script?
2- Do you know how I can do this task?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 1):

**For Q1**, from the functional point of view, there is no difference between scaling up an Azure Analysis service using local Powershell script or using Azure automation Powershell runbook. Both of them will need to import Azure PowerShell modules and call functions.

For local Powershell script, you should install modules you need with command: [Install-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.1), and for Azure automation Powershell runbook, if you need some module, you can [manage your modules on the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-az-modules)

**For Q2**, if you want to change your Analysis service pricing tier(SKU) to get more QPU, you can just use the PowerShell command below:

```
Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer -sku <sku name, such as B1,B2> -Name <your service name> -ResourceGroupName <the resource group name>
```

[image]

This is [the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.analysisservices/set-azanalysisservicesserver?view=azps-5.1.0) of this command.
If you are not sure about how to use Azure PowerShell command, please see [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-5.1.0).